# how to post status on facebook using php code?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

I created an app for posting status on fb as a below image, [image]

and my code is :

```
<?php

require_once("src/facebook.php");

$appId='1462917680664dfd628';
$secret='65b160jkjdfj155615a3659ee441b1eac2942d';

$returnUrl='http://localhost/www/newOne/';

$permission='manage_pages, publish_stream';
$action_name = 'Action Link in the Footer of the Post';
$facebook=new Facebook(array('appId'=>$appId  , 'secret'=>$secret));

$fbUser=$facebook->getUser();

if($fbUser)
{
    try{

        $accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
         if (!empty( $accessToken )) {
                 $attachment = array(
                     'access_token' => $accessToken,
                     'message' => $msg,
                     'name' => $title,
                     'link' => $returnUrl,
                     'description' => $desc,
                     'actions' => json_encode(array('name' => $action_name,'link' => $returnUrl))
                  );

                $status = $facebook->api("/me/feed", "post", $attachment);
         } else {
                $status = 'No access token recieved';
         }

    }catch(FacebookApiException $er)
    {
        echo $er->getMessage();
    }
}else
{
    $loginUrl=$fb->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>$permission ,'redirect-uri'=>$returnUrl));

    echo '<a href="'.$loginUrl.'">Login</a>';
}



?>
```

and the result is :

[image]

I used localhost for this propose , someone told me to change it to real server I did it but I got the same error , I have been searched for many times in Google but no useful answer , someone tell me what's wrong with my code or my Facebook app.

Answer (score 0):

The domain of your `$returnUrl` must be in the `App Domains` setting for it to work.

Comment: @ShanazK No, I can't, because your issue is in your Facebook app settings.

Comment: i put on the real server I got this error :

500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: how to do this sorry ?

Answer (score 0):

you can't post on facebook on localhost. you have to use server to post on facebook wall. suppose you have domain name like www.abc.com than you have to put this domain information when you are creating facebook App ID and APP Secret. Once you create this APP ID and APP Secret than you can use with this domain only. You can not use these App ID and APP Secret with other domain name.

Comment: thank you, please have look my code it's right or not ?

Comment: it seems like correct but you have to put this code on server and you have to create new App Id and APP Secret using your domain.

Comment: I did it but I got this ERROR : 

500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: what's your domain? it should'nt be like 192.168.125.32.

Comment: my domain is :162.144.251.109

test.ethraa-hosting.com